# Installing SafeNet's Sentinel USB dongle on Windows 7 with non-standard "Documents" directory/folder

Tags: installation

I work on a computer where the folder "Documents" is mapped to a network drive (H:). From time to time that causes problems with software installation.

Recently I was installing IAR Embedded Workbench and as part of it the drivers for SafeNet's Sentinel USB dongle which holds the license for that piece of software.

After switching to Windows 7 the part of the installation which installed the drivers for the dongle failed and as a result I could not use the software. The installation failed with message box (entitled "Sentinel Protection Installer - Installer Information" saying:

"Error 1327. Invalid Drive H:\"

Initially, the tech support at SafeNet recommended to clean up the installation with their SSD clean-up software (I tried both 32-bit and 64-bit versions) and reinstall the drivers with a separate installation bundle (http://c3.safenet-inc.com/downloads/8/0/804F8C5F-F88F-4443-8871-2AD993DC33DB/Sentinel%20Protection%20Installer%207.6.5.exe). However, that installation failed just the same.

An attempt to use "Update Driver Software" option in Device Manager with a bare driver files from a custom ZIP provided by SafeNet failed as well.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I was in touch with SafeNet - they were not able to help.

Comment: Anyway, in the end the solution was to run the following command to temporarily reassign the network drive back to the system drive:

    subst H: "C:\Windows"

Answer (score -1):

The simple and quick resolutions to repair 1327 error are outlined below:

```
Enter Valid Path of My Documents in your Registry
Make Required Changes
Restore the Original Drive Letter
Temporarily Map a Folder to the Drive Letter
```

Take from

[Fix error1327](http://sorcim.com/knowledgebase/1327.html)